# Optimize WORD VBA - If, Case

Tags: microsoft-word, performance, vba

I implemented this following code to go though 11 dropdown content controls to color 2 cells in a WORD table based on the user entries - RED, YELLOW, GREEN, and no entry.

This seems to slow down the loading of the document quite a bit - is there a way to either optimize the code or only compute it after the document is closed? Ideally it would be the first option.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
    If ContentControl.Tag = "status_1" Then
    Select Case ContentControl.Range.Text
    Case "GREEN"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
         ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(1).Cell(2, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    Case "YELLOW"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(1).Cell(2, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    Case "RED"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(1).Cell(2, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Case Else
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(100, 50, 150)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(1).Cell(2, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(100, 50, 150)
        
        End Select
        End If
        
         If ContentControl.Tag = "status_2" Then
    Select Case ContentControl.Range.Text
    Case "GREEN"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
         ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(1).Cell(3, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    Case "YELLOW"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(1).Cell(3, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    Case "RED"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(1).Cell(3, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Case Else
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(100, 50, 150)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(1).Cell(3, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(100, 50, 150)
        
        End Select
        End If
        
         If ContentControl.Tag = "status_3" Then
    Select Case ContentControl.Range.Text
    Case "GREEN"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
         ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(1).Cell(4, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    Case "YELLOW"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(1).Cell(4, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    Case "RED"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(1).Cell(4, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Case Else
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(100, 50, 150)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(1).Cell(4, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(100, 50, 150)
        
        End Select
        End If
    
         If ContentControl.Tag = "status_4" Then
    Select Case ContentControl.Range.Text
    Case "GREEN"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
         ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(1).Cell(5, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    Case "YELLOW"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(1).Cell(5, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    Case "RED"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(1).Cell(5, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Case Else
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(100, 50, 150)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(1).Cell(5, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(100, 50, 150)
        
        End Select
        End If
        
            If ContentControl.Tag = "status_5" Then
    Select Case ContentControl.Range.Text
    Case "GREEN"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
         ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(1).Cell(6, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    Case "YELLOW"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(1).Cell(6, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    Case "RED"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(1).Cell(6, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Case Else
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(100, 50, 150)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(1).Cell(6, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(100, 50, 150)
        
        End Select
        End If
        
            If ContentControl.Tag = "status_6" Then
    Select Case ContentControl.Range.Text
    Case "GREEN"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
         ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(1).Cell(7, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    Case "YELLOW"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(1).Cell(7, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    Case "RED"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(1).Cell(7, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Case Else
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(100, 50, 150)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(1).Cell(7, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(100, 50, 150)
        
        End Select
        End If
        
                 If ContentControl.Tag = "status_7" Then
    Select Case ContentControl.Range.Text
    Case "GREEN"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
         ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(3).Cell(2, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    Case "YELLOW"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(3).Cell(2, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    Case "RED"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(3).Cell(2, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Case Else
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(100, 50, 150)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(3).Cell(2, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(100, 50, 150)
        
        End Select
        End If
        
                         If ContentControl.Tag = "status_8" Then
    Select Case ContentControl.Range.Text
    Case "GREEN"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
         ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(3).Cell(3, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    Case "YELLOW"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(3).Cell(3, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    Case "RED"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(3).Cell(3, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Case Else
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(100, 50, 150)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(3).Cell(3, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(100, 50, 150)
        
        End Select
        End If
        
                              If ContentControl.Tag = "status_9" Then
    Select Case ContentControl.Range.Text
    Case "GREEN"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
         ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(3).Cell(4, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    Case "YELLOW"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(3).Cell(4, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    Case "RED"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(3).Cell(4, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Case Else
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(100, 50, 150)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(3).Cell(4, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(100, 50, 150)
        
        End Select
        End If
        
                                      If ContentControl.Tag = "status_10" Then
    Select Case ContentControl.Range.Text
    Case "GREEN"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
         ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(3).Cell(5, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    Case "YELLOW"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(3).Cell(5, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    Case "RED"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(3).Cell(5, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Case Else
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(100, 50, 150)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(3).Cell(5, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(100, 50, 150)
        
        End Select
        End If
        
                                              If ContentControl.Tag = "status_11" Then
    Select Case ContentControl.Range.Text
    Case "GREEN"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
         ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(3).Cell(6, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    Case "YELLOW"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(3).Cell(6, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    Case "RED"
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(3).Cell(6, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Case Else
        ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(100, 50, 150)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(3).Cell(6, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(100, 50, 150)
        
        End Select
        End If
        
End Sub
```

Comment: I guess Document_Close is the second option but I would rather have a faster code if possible. I feel the case function might just be to inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is very voluminous, so may take a long time to
compile on loading the document.

If I understood the code correctly,
you have basically duplicated the same code under several IF tests,
where the only difference is the index: `Cell(2, 1)`,
`Cell(3, 1)` etc. and that of the table.

I suggest using variables for the cell and table indexes
and writing the code only once,
similar to the following (untested) code:

```
icell = 0
itable = 0

Select Case ContentControl.Range.Text
  Case "status_1"
    icell = 2
    itable = 1
  Case "status_2"
    icell = 3
    itable = 1
... etc ...
  Case "status_11"
    icell = 6
    itable = 3
End Select

If icell <> 0
  Select Case ContentControl.Range.Text
    Case "GREEN"
      ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
      ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(itable).Cell(icell, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    Case "YELLOW"
       ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
       ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(itable).Cell(icell, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    Case "RED"
      ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
      ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(itable).Cell(icell, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Case Else
      ContentControl.Range.Cells(1).Next.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(100, 50, 150)
      ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Tables(itable).Cell(icell, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(100, 50, 150)
  End Select
End If
```

I haven't tested the above code.

Comment: Prefect thanks! I had a bunch of links in the document that were actually causing the slowdown not the code - will still implement it your way if it works!

Comment: Similarly, I would probably consider making a new variable (such as `DIm newCellColor as Long`) and assign it to one of the `RGB()` values (RGB returns a long representing the "hex value") and then do the actual work of color assignment (e.g. contentcontrol & active document = newCellColor) once, immediately after the `end select`